# Asker-Alert for "opinion-based" and similar questions?

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed a lot of newcomer-questions with wording like:

- [...] is it possible [...]
- [...] is there any way to [...]
- [...] do you think [...]
- is/are [...] actually useful?

etc. It would be great if, during the O.P. *composing* such questions, the site regex'd their text and alerted the user for certain patterns, sort-of as a guide while they get accustomed to how things work here.

So for the above questions, an alert appears similar to `If you ask this, your question may be closed as opinion-based! Each question must be directly answerable, and not by discussion or opinion.`

Same with:

- [...] Arduino / Due [...] --> `Note, your question must be an actual electronics design question.  If not, we have a dedicated stack for Arduino questions...`
- [...] Rpi / raspberry / raspbian [...] --> `Note, your question must be an actual electronics design question.  If not, we have a dedicated stack for Raspberry Pi questions...`
- [...] namespace WPFToArduino [...] --> `Note, C# is unusual in programming electronics; are you sure you want to ask this, and the question is on-topic here (electronics design)?`
- [...] mass / force / subatomic / quantum / quark / strong force / weak force / radiation [...] --> `Is this question is on-topic here (electronics design)? If it's more of a physics question, consider our Physics Stack...`
- [...] washer / dryer / microwave oven / space heater / razor / water heater [...] --> `Are you sure this question is on-topic here (electronics design)? If not, consider asking on our Home Improvement stack.`

Sort-of like a pre-moderator intervention tool, to thwart a percentage of questions from being asked in the first place, and suggest askers' questions appear in the correct stack instantly.

And the home improvement and physics stacks for instance, could regex and suggest questions to us which match our wheelhouse.

Comment: I think a more sophisticated filtering system when writing a question is a great idea. I don't think this site helps itself by not being clear enough to new users raising a question. Mind you I still see seasoned veterans asking these sorts of inapplicable questions too.

Comment: I've been guilty in the past also; nobody's perfect and we're all still learning.  But many newcomers seem to err towards laziness; they might think "this is probably a shady question for this nit-picky *forum* whose rules I just skipped over, but I already spent three whole minutes writing it, so POST."  If there was such an alert, maybe they'd think twice.  I'm learning that all success in life hinges on thinking twice (recursively.)

Answer (score -1):

I think that would be a great idea, in the past stack exchange usually does not have time or resources to implement such changes, so keep your expectations low. Another problem is usually changes like this are implemented across all sites, so it has to work for all sites. I will try and forward this up the chain when the opportunity becomes available